# Задать размер в конструкторе коллекции LinkedList<> в C#

Tags: c#, коллекции, конструктор, linked-list

Нужно создать конструктор с параметром, где параметр-размер коллекции. Не совсем понимаю как это адекватно сделать с двусвязным списком. Коллекция обобщенная, туда передается объект класса Person

```
 class MyCollection<T> : IEnumerable<T> where T: Person 
{ 
    
    LinkedList<T> col1 = new LinkedList<T>();

    public int Count
    {
        get { return col1.Count; }
    }

    public MyCollection()
    { }

    //в этот конструктор надо передать размер коллекции
    public MyCollection()
    {
        col1 = new LinkedList<T>();
    }
```

Comment: Зачем связанному списку знать размер коллекции?

Comment: Затем, что преподаватель требует наличия конструктора с параметром, где параметр-размер коллекции

Comment: Да тупо добавьте свойство размер и инициализируйте. А вот как это использовать это пусть препод сам думает

Comment: Я думаю если это ArrayList то смысл есть а вот для связного списка смысла нет вводить махCount или вызывать исключение если в список хотят добавить элементов больше чем мах

Answer (score 0):

Думаю вам надо что-то такое

```
class MyCollection<T> : IEnumerable<T> where T: Person 
{ 
    
    LinkedList<T> col1 = new LinkedList<T>();

    public int Count
    {
        get { return col1.Count; }
    }

    public int MaxCount
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public MyCollection()
    { }

    //в этот конструктор надо передать размер коллекции
    public MyCollection(int maxCount)
    {
        col1 = new LinkedList<T>();
        MaxCount = maxCount;
    }
    
    public int Add(T t){
      if (Count+1 > MaxCount) throw new  Exception("достигнут предел списка или что-то в этом духе");
      ....
    }
```

Дело в том что в основе связного списка лежит не массив, так чтобы выделить заранее массив для указателей добавляемых объектов.